# google-cloud-dataflow-logback json loggig is not working

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have configured logback on top of slf4j.But logging message in json format is not working in DataflowRuner.The same is working in DirectRunner.

Comment: Hello, could you expand a bit on your use case here? It seems like your trying to use your own third party logging framework logback when GCP already provides such service through Cloud Logging and Stackdriver API's.

Comment: Sample logs and some configuration will really help.